# lxpanel launch bar icons are broken

Tags: ubuntu, lxde

I'm using lxpanel on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop and facing this issue. Trouble is that the launchbar on the panel isn't displaying icons for some apps (or rather, the icons being displayed are generic white ones with a red cross-mark in between).

[image]

As you can see in the above image, the third icon for the geany app is problematic and isn't displayed and the same happens if I put firefox in the launchbar. However, all other icons seem to be displayed properly. Also, its noteworthy that issue with geany/firefox icons is only in the launchbar, in the taskbar and the main menu, it is displayed properly. I've also ensured that geany icons exist in the `/usr/share/icons` folder. I've also tried changing the gtk themes using `lxappearance`, but it didn't do any good. Can someone help me with this?

**EDIT**

When I right-click on the icons and go to the launch-bar settings, I can see a selector dialog like this from where I chose geany/firefox, but I see no way to change the icon:

[image]

Comment: Can you right-click it and manually set the icon in the "launcher properties" or whatever it might be called?

Comment: @Fiximan When I right-click and go to "launcher settings", all I can do is select the apps (see Edit for the screenshot), there is no way to change the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully changed the icon as follows (I'll use Iceweasel for my example):

1.Check your home folder for the LXpanel configuration at `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel` for a block specifying the launchbar:

```
Plugin {
  type=launchbar
  Config {
    Button {
      id=/usr/share/applications/lxterminal.desktop
    }
    Button {
      id=/usr/share/applications/iceweasel.desktop
    }
    Button {
      id=menu://applications/Internet/icedove.desktop
    }
  }
}
```

2.We found where the `iceweasel.desktop` config file is located. Now we look at said file `/usr/share/applications/iceweasel.desktop` for the `Icon` line:

```
grep Icon /usr/share/applications/iceweasel.desktop
Icon=icewesael
```

3.We change it to our new icon (as root) e.g. the `icedove` icon using a full path entry, so now the line reads:

```
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/icedove.png
```

4.Restart the panel

```
lxpanelctl restart
```

Now you just need to figure out where your specific missing icon is.

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed working, but I really don't understand *how* it is working. In `/usr/share/applications/*.desktop` files, agreed that only `geany` is mentioned, not the entire path to `geany.png`, but same is the case for other apps like `Icon=thunderbird` in case of thunderbird, or `Icon=dia` in case of Dia, but lxpanel still finds their icons. Why is it not able to find with the default name (`geany`) only in the case of geany and firefox?

Comment: @PrahladYeri I honestly cannot tell you as I do not know how it is managed. I just had a lucky shot. Is the icon in the proper subdirs of `/usr/share/icons/`? Could it be a case issue? Btw: updated answer: the panel can be reloaded instead of the need for a new login.

Comment: Yes, icons exist in `/usr/share/icons` and also in `/usr/share/pixmaps`. Perhaps it was due to installing multiple DEs that this could happen? I switched from Unity to GNOME to XFCE to Openbox+lxpanel and finally settled on lxde! Maybe an after effect of that. In any case, I also don't want to bother about the *why* as long as it works. The day I decide to format and do a clean install, this issue will hopefully cease to exist.